# How to clear strings before read and transform str to int

Tags: python

I've been working on bank app. I've created login/register system where each user appears as a txt file. Each txt file contains 4 lines: login,password,security code and forth is balance after deposit or withdraw. I'm strugling how to create forth line. In my existing code the given deposit is written next to exisitng value. Is is possible to read string line written in txt so I can add it to given deposoit balance and afterwards display one value? Also the default value of 4th line is 0 and it is a string.

```
        self.balance = int(self.balance) + self.amt
        file=open(self.name, "a+")    # <----- Creates line in user's file.
        file.write(int(self.balance))
        messagebox.showinfo("balance","You have deposit: "+str(self.balance))


file=open(self.username_info, "w") <------ All user s are created as txt file

file.write(self.username_info+"\n") 

file.write(self.password_info+"\n")   

file.write(self.code_info+"\n")

file.write(self.cash)
```

Comment: Ok I have figured how to put value which is balance + deposit however the new values are written next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the balance deposit like so `balance = file.readlines()[3]` if the file is open in "r" mode, then do whatever operation you like with this variable, then rewrite the four lines.

Opening the file in "write mode" ensures that no data is appended. Everything is just overwritten instead of modified, but since you only have 4 lines it's alright.

```
# Open the file, read its content, close the file.
file = open(file_name, "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

# Get the interesting info from the stored lines.
login = lines[0].rstrip() # <- add .rstrip() here if you want to get rid of the spaces and line feeds.
password = lines[1].rstrip()
security_code = lines[2].rstrip()
balance = int(lines[3]) # <- notice the int() for conversion.

# Do something on the balance, for example:
balance += deposit

# Open the file and write back the 4 lines, with the 4th modified.
file = open(file_name, "w")
file.write(login + "\n") 
file.write(password + "\n")   
file.write(security_code + "\n")
file.write(str(balance) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Here is a more compact version if you are interested:

```
# Open the file, read its content, close the file.
with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Open the file and write back the 4 lines, with the 4th modified.
with open(file_name, "w") as file:
    file.write(lines[0])
    file.write(lines[1])  
    file.write(lines[2])
    file.write("%d \n" %(int(lines[3])+deposit))
```

Comment: so test=file.readlines()[3] and then test.write(str(self.balance)) ? Also is is possible to read written string as int so I can mathemticaly add the two value to obtain one value ?

Comment: No you cannot do `test.write` because `test` is the variable in which you stored the result of the 4th line! You meant `file.write`?

Comment: If you want to convert a string to an int you just need to call `int()`. For example `number = int(string_to_convert)`.

Comment: One again according to your code. Balance is storage for 4th line so to change it I have to open file again but "w" and then write the new content ?

Comment: Exactly. I edited to give a complete example, hopefully that helps.

Comment: You are my hero ! I've spent 3 days to figure it out. Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("info","r") as fd:
    username,password,code,cash= [i.strip() for i in fd if len(i.strip())>1]
```

Comment: care to explain a little more?

Comment: This answer would be much better if it included an explanation along with the code. For example, for someone new to programming they will have no idea if this is extra code, or code that replaces one or more lines of the original code.